# Tables from two different databases in a DBML?

Tags: linq-to-sql, multiple-databases

After dragging two tables in from one database, I switch to another and drag a table in. Now I get a message if I want to replace the connection string with the new one. I want tables from multiple databases in one DBML. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe that what you're looking for is possible, since the DataContext would then not have any easy way of resolving results from two separate databases.

If you're looking to create domain objects from two separate databases, then your best bet would be to have two separate DBML's, then use a bridge (GOF) or some other related design pattern to instantiate your domain objects.

Comment: Do you have links to how this would work?  I think i have a similar situation.  I have one master database which contains a list of clients and the server name and database name for each of the clients.  They all have an identical database structure, So, I would like to fill the model from different databases depending on the client selected.

Comment: @stephenbayer - your situation is actually a bit different. Since data isn't actually spread around multiple DB's your job is a bit easier. Create a service (web, soap, rest, doesn't matter for this discussion) that will know how to find a connection string or database name prefix (more secure) to your DB's. Use a client identifier as an index for find the specific database. Your app can query this client db for info on how to connect to the specific db.

Answer (score 5):

It is entirely possible to reference multiple databases within the same DBML, PROVIDED those databases reside on the same SQL Server.

In Visual Studio, right-click on the DBML, click "Open with..." , and select XML (Text) Editor with Encoding.

You will see your first table that you dragged in looks like this:

> <Table Name="dbo.MyTable1fromMyDatabase1" Member="MyTable1fromMyDatabase1">

For your tables from other databases you wish to add, enter them like this:

> <Table Name="MyDatabase2.dbo.MyTable1fromMyDatabase2" Member="MyTable1fromMyDatabase2">

This will work assuming the same login works for both databases, and your `LINQ` expressions can now query across both databases!

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to create a server link on on database that points to the other and make aliases to the remote tables from the "local" DB. I believe then you'd be able to reference them as if they were all in the same database.

Comment: while this is a technically correct answer, wouldn't this be a poor practice to follow? I've had to deal with linked servers in the past, and in my experience, it hasn't been pretty in terms of maintainability or performance

Answer (score 0):

We can also create a view that queries the table in the other database. We can select, insert and update this view, which will affect the table in the other database as well.